# Counting filled rows issue in datagridview using binding source in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, lambda

I'm using Json to populate DataGridView with BindingSource method. As I go along I wonder why does the count of rows are still 1, when there is no value being selected according to my where statement. Please help me.

Here is my sample code:

```
public void JsonPopulateDGV(string JsonDir, int partsId, string fileName)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(JsonDir);
        var jSectionCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSectionCollection>(json) ?? new JSectionCollection();
        BindingSource src = new BindingSource();
        src.DataSource = jSectionCollection.JSections.Where(x => x.PartsId == partsId).Where(s=>s.FileDir == fileName);

        dataGridSections.DataSource = src;

        Console.WriteLine(src.Count);
    }
```

Comment: Does it add a header row automatically with the column names?

Comment: @RyanWilson Header row are not visible, but the cells are there with no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute `Where` by calling `ToArray` or `ToList`. You can also combine two where statements into one:

```
src.DataSource = jSectionCollection.JSections
                                .Where(x => x.PartsId == partsId && x.FileDir == fileName)
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: Hmmmm. I didn't think of it that this will work yet it does. Thank you so much.